# How to enable NASM syntax highlighting in emacs?

Tags: macos, emacs, nasm

I'm using the `nasm` assembler and writing code in intel syntax and want to turn on syntax highlighting permanently. How can I do this?

I'm using OSX 10.8.5 and emacs 23.9.

I've tried following this [tutorial](http://matthieuhauglustaine.blogspot.com/2011/08/nasm-mode-for-emacs.html) and added the following to my `~/.emacs` file:

```
(autoload 'nasm-mode "~/.emacs.d/nasm-mode.el" "" t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.\\(asm\\|s\\)$" . nasm-mode))
```

But I'm still not able to get syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the extension you are using is .nasm, you need to add this line also:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.nasm\\'" . nasm-mode))
```

The tutorial does not work for you because it assumes the extensions ".s" and ".asm".  With the line above, the extension ".nasm" is also considered.